# Adjustments to (Linear Regression) Forecast

Tags: regression, forecasting, adjustment

Full disclosure: I am not a statistician, nor do I claim to be one.  I am a lowly IT administrator.  Please play gentle with me. :)

I am responsible for collecting and forecasting disk storage use for our enterprise.  We collect our storage use monthly and use a simple rolling twelve month linear regression for forecasts (in other words, only the previous twelve months of data are considered when making a projection).  We use this information for allocation and capital expense planning, e.g. "Based on this model, we will need to purchase x amount if storage in y months to meet our needs."  This all works well enough to suit our needs.

Periodically, we have large one-time movements in our numbers that throws the forecasting off.  For example, someone finds 500GB of old backups that aren't needed anymore and deletes them.  Good for them for reclaiming the space!  However our forecasts are now skewed way off by this large drop in one month.  We have always just accepted that a drop like this takes 9-10 months to make its way out of the models, but that can be a really long time if we are entering capital expense planning season.

I'm wondering if there is a way to handle these one-time variances such that the forecasted values aren't impacted as much (e.g. the slope of the line doesn't change as dramatically), but they are taken into account (e.g. a one-time change in the y-value associated with a particular point in time).  Our first attempts at tackling this have yielded some ugly results (e.g. exponential growth curves).  We do all of our processing in SQL Server if that matters.

Comment: Excellent question.  Just a quick clarification.  Would you like to predict these events, or, once they happen, adjust the model predictions given your new information?

Comment: Right, it's not clear if you are trying to "smooth" out these rare events like the 500GB example so they don't impact your results as much or if you are trying to account more them since you want to capture when bitch adjustments to store are made?  The difference is subtle:  In the first, you want to almost ignore the new point (rare event), but int he second, you want to emphasize the point (rare event).  If it's the former, robust regression is probably a simple method for you since you are already using linear regression.  See here:  http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/rreg.htm

Comment: Also, do you use any software to make your predictions and do you use confidence intervals?

Comment: I can add an adjustment after the fact.  In fact, most of the time I won't know about a major deviation until I look at the next month's numbers and see a big change.  I'm not using any software to make the predictions; just a stored procedure in SQL Server to calculate my regression values.

Comment: Quick reactions: (a) I'd probably first fit a very basic AR(1) to changes in log disk usage? You''d basically be estimating some long term growth rate in disk usage, and how quickly the growth rate in disk usage moves back to that trend after a shock. (aa) You could use other data too and fit a VAR (vector autoregression). (b) throwing out all data > 12 months may not make be the optimal thing to do.  (c) regular OLS minimizes the sum of squares. You could use a different penalty function (eg. Huber) which is more robust to outliers.

Comment: Perhaps you could turn each point into (change from prior point) and then forecast that. So when these spikes happen, it would only be a single anomalous point. You could remove those points from your set of historical numbers when building the regression.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at are outliers.  If you have reason to believe the outlier(s) do not represent your data, you may remove them.  In a validated environment, you would have to investigate each one and justify them, but in your case you can probably just delete them.

If you're looking to find these data points automatically, look at Cook's Distance, which analyzes the residuals and can make a mathematical determination of reject criteria (typically 4/n, where n is 12 in your case)

Another suggestion is to open up the data range of your data, can you look at two years, or are data that old completely irrelevant?  That of course would reduce the impact of an outlier or two, and also gives more power to analysis methods such as Cook's Distance.

Now the tricky thing can be an offset - so if that outlier causes the entire line to jump down, it will cause the regression to face down even if there's a general upward trend.
To prevent that, you can plot the *change* in hard drive space.  Removing the outlier removes the spurious data points, and you can see the overall trend in *change* in hard drive space, leading to more accurate conclusions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I understand of your situation: You have a forecast, a regression model that you evaluate monthly, of your storage needs for "y" months, that uses the data over the previous year from the current month. Once and awhile, someone deletes a chunk of data and suddenly the slope of the line changes dramatically from the usual forecast. This change in the slope effects capital expense planning for however long it takes for the point to run its course through the model.

Your resistance to throwing out the data is appropriate. You have decisions to make a-priori. How to define and handle outliers. Outliers can be defined based on business and/or statistical definitions. I am going to make the assumption that the outliers you are concerned about are simply "obvious".

Once found, we investigate outliers to see if they are generated from a real data generating process, then we handle them according to our a-priori decided upon procedures. These procedures can be anything from 'trimming' a certain percentage of data points from one or both edges of data, to replacing the value, to controlling for the specific outliers, changing the model so it uses a different underlying distribution, or changing the model so it uses a different central tendency.

One way to handle the outliers after they are investigated, assuming the outliers are relatively infrequent, is to add them as a predictor in the model. Each outlier gets an entire predictor. The predictor would be a seperate column that would predict one for the data point that is the outlier and zero otherwise. Once controlled for, they will not pull the slope of the model anymore. This procedure has several advantages, one being that no data are thrown out or changed to some other value.

Some disadvantage include taking extra time to model the outlier and having to re-specify the model each month as the column of the outlier moves through the modeling year window. However, any action with outliers will require extra time in modeling, which is a necessary step in cleaning the data. Also, if I understand correctly, you're respecifying the forecast each month anyway.

```
Example Regression formula:
    memory_capital = ... + mem_usage_nov + mem_usage_dec + outlier_column1_dec + ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple suggestion.  I don't know whether it works for you and maybe I should have made it as a comment, but it seems you need more privileges to make a comment than to make a reply.

If I understand correctly, the figures you are using are the amounts of storage you are using each month.  Probably these usualy increase, and you want to predict what the amount will be at some time in the future if trends continue.  Once you realise that your big change has happened (e.g. that 500 GB has been released) can you go back and change the previous months' figures (e.g. delete 500 GB from all of them)?  Basically what you would be doing is to adjust the previous months' figures to what they should have been, if you knew then what you know now.

Of course I don't recommend this unless you make sure you can go back to the old figures.  But the forecasting you want to do sounds like it could even be done in Excel, in which case you can have as many versions as you want.